# how to make semantic label image?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv

Now I want to train my own image data in caffe using [SegNet](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/projects/segnet/).

But at the first step we need label our own image like these:

[image]

I have tried to search github but cannot find anything. So my question is anyone know which tool can make semantic label image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answer by @rayryeng a tool called [sloth](https://github.com/cvhciKIT/sloth) is great to finish these task in simple way. However, if I have more than 20 object waiting for me to classify, sloth is not a ideal tools. Thus I develop a simple tool which call [IsLabel](https://github.com/chenzomi12/iscreate_label) to finish these problem with few algorithms.

And the result look like these while using IsLabel just took me 40s:

INPUT:

[image]

OUTPUT:

[image]

I know its not perfect but it work fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Check out a tool called [sloth](https://github.com/cvhciKIT/sloth): https://github.com/cvhciKIT/sloth, which is an open-source tool written in Python with PyQt for creating ground truth computer vision datasets for a wide array of applications, such as semantically creating data like you have above.

If you don't like sloth, you can use any image editing software, like [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) where you would make one layer per label and use polygons and flood fill of different hues to create your data.  You would then merge all of the layers together to make a final image that you would use for your purposes.

However, as user Miki mentioned (see discussion thread below), creating new datasets from the beginning **will** take a considerable amount of effort. It is highly advisable that you don't create this on your own as you need a lot of data to ensure your algorithms are performing correctly. You'll need the help of other (hopefully willing) PhD students, preferably those you know personally or work with you in your lab or workplace to help manually curate this data for you.

If this isn't an option, you can use crowd sourced funded places like [Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome)  where you can outsource the work to willing individuals where you inform them of the task at hand and you pay a small amount per image. This would be something to consider if you can't find many people to help you.

All in all, this will take a considerable amount of effort, not only in terms of time but in terms of people if you want to create a large data set within a short span of time. I would recommend you simply use established datasets, such as what you have referenced from Cambridge, or Miki suggested [LabelMe by Antonio Torralba](http://labelme.csail.mit.edu/Release3.0/browserTools/php/matlab_toolbox.php) which not only is a toolbox for annotating images from his LabelMe dataset but it also allows you to do the same for your own images.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi rayryeng! I think that you should mention also that you'll need _a lot_ of poor PhD students to label the large amount of images needed for training, or something like amazon mechanical turk. Or better, you can use public datasets already labelled (labelme dataset of Torralba, on the top of my head, but probably there are better ones around)

Comment: @Miki completely agree with you!

Comment: @Miki oh yes. Lol. I remember I didn't have the luxury of mechanical turk... Or other PhD students helping me out. I'll mention this. Good idea. Thanks... No upvote? Pffft. Thanks there too :p.

Comment: Oh.. I just forgot..  ;)

Comment: @Miki hehe I was only kidding :) I appreciated your comment more. Thank you for the vote BTW.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using https://www.labelbox.io/. They [open sourced](https://github.com/labelbox/labelbox) a lot of their code and have a hosting platform to manage the whole labeling process end to end.

Here is an example of segmentation

[image]

And you can export labels with a mask.

[image]